# ¿como puedo esperar a que en una automatizacion espere a que el usuario (responda y seleccione) para continuar la automatizacion?

Tags: python, csv, selenium, web-scrapping, opencsv

buen día, espero darme a entender estoy tratando de automatizar un proceso, es llenar un formulario y estoy utilizando python selenium y un archivo csv, el proceso funciona pero me gustaria saber si existe la manera de que el codigo espere a que en una parte el usuario seleccione el dato correcto de una lista y luego continúe, me explico: en una parte del codigo me pide un codigo postal, el motor de busqueda arroja varias colonias y el usuario debe seleccionar la colonia correcta y dar en siguiente, luego se debe llenar automaticamente todos los campos restantes, hay manera de que pueda realizar este proceso?

el codigo funciona porque le di 20 segundos de tiempo para que el usuario responda antes de que mande el click de siguiente, esto no es tan practico ya que 20 segundos a veces no alcanza el tiempo de revisar la lista que puede ser de muchas colonias otra que el codigo postal arroje solo una colonia y se tenga que esperar 19 segundos a que pase a la siguiente pantalla. quisiera saber si se puede realizar este procedimiento que el usuario decida la colonia y de clic en siguiente y luego continuar la automatizacion. gracias espero que me haya dado a entender[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    for line in csv_reader:
  try:
    select = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "direccionRecoleccion"))
    select.select_by_visible_text('TI MYTS')
    select2 = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "servicioDisponible"))
    time.sleep(1)
    select2.select_by_visible_text('EXPRESS')
    time.sleep(1)
    select3 = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "tipoMensajeriaExpress"))
    select3.select_by_visible_text('Sobre')
    time.sleep(1)
    select4 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input")
    select4.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    codigopostal = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'codigoPostal') #aqui ingresa el codigo psotal
    codigopostal.send_keys(line[4]) #envia datos del csv
    time.sleep(20) #tiempo que el usuario escoja
    enter = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section/form/div[2]/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/input")
    enter.click() #automatizar click para pasar al siguiente formulario
    time.sleep(1)
    alias = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'consignatario.apodo')
    alias = alias.send_keys(line[5])
    consignatario = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'consignatario.nombre')
    consignatario = consignatario.send_keys('REPRESENTANTE LEGAL')
    time.sleep(1)
    nombre = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'consignatario.compania')
    nombre = nombre.send_keys(line[0])
    time.sleep(1)
    calle = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'consignatario.direccion')
    calle = calle.send_keys(line[1])
    time.sleep(1)
    numero = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'numeroExt')
    numero = numero.send_keys(line[2])
    time.sleep(1)
    correo = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'consignatario.correo')
    correo = correo.send_keys(line[6])
    telefono = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'consignatario.tel')
    telefono = telefono.send_keys(line[7])
    peso = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'informacionGuia.peso')
    peso.clear()
    peso = peso.send_keys('0.5')
    time.sleep(2)
    observaciones = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'informacionGuia.observaciones')
    observaciones = observaciones.send_keys('Colonia' + line[3] + " " + "calle" + " " + line[1] + " " + 'Número' + line[2])
    time.sleep(2)
    aceptar = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'aceptaCondiciones').click()
    time.sleep(4)
    regresar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[51]/td/input[1]")
    regresar.click()
    time.sleep(1)
  except:
    pass
```

Comment: ¿En tu escenario no es viable seleccionar una opción dentro de la prueba automática?

Comment: Hola, desafortunadamente no es viable ya que la base de datos contiene nombres de colonias que no hacen match al 100% con la que arroja el motor de busqueda, por eso se necesita esa interaccion por parte del usuario que seleccione la que mas se asemeje a la base de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo eliminaría la automatización del click que espera 20 segundos y pasa al siguiente formulario, haría que el usuario llene el dato y haga click.

Esto con la finalidad de tener un evento que espere la existencia de un elemento del siguiente formulario, solo cuando el usuario haga click y por ende se pase al siguiente formulario el evento se detendra y continuara la ejecución.

```
while bool(driver.find_elements(By.NAME,'consignatario.apodo')) == False: #validar la precencia del elemento web
i=i+1
time.sleep(1)
print('Esperando que el usuario haga click para encontrar elemento, tiempo: '+str(i))
```

Mientras que no se haga click para pasar al siguiente formulario la existencia del elemento será falso, luego al hacer click y encontrar el elemento su existencia será verdadera y continuara con la siguiente instrucción.

En este ejemplo ingreso a google y espero a que el usuario haga click en "voy a tener suerte", solo si hace click se procede a desplegar el idioma del siguiente formulario

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
def HacerClick(driver, locator):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 11).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator)).click()
s = Service(r'C:\\webDrivers\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
i=0
while bool(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="searchinput"]')) == False: #validar la precencia del elemento web
   i=i+1
   time.sleep(1)
   print('Esperando el click, tiempo: '+str(i))
HacerClick(driver, ("xpath", '//*[@id="lang-chooser"]'))
time.sleep(2)
```